# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '(Function Name)') but works for all

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It works for all but this didn't, I had all for this following code:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
  this.state = {
   addchange: ''
  }
 this.handleInputAddChange = this.handleInputAddChange.bind(this);
}
```

```
handleInputAddChange = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
   [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  })
}
```

```
<input type="text" name="addchange" onChange={this.handleInputAddChange} />
```

and pops ups the weird error, and for the last time I doubled check that most of my code like this works but this appeared React.js's error screen like this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handleInputAddChange')
```

Note that its the same format from my other code like this. and its weird why it didn't work in this one anymore.

Comment: handleInputAddChange is arrow function, so you don't have to manually bind `this`. try removing `this.handleInputAddChange = this.handleInputAddChange.bind(this);
}` from constructor

Comment: @GulamHussain - `bind` doesn't do any *good*, but doesn't do any harm either. (They should remove it, but removing it won't help.)

Comment: The problem isn't `handleInputChange`, it's where you're *using* it (`this.handleInputChange`, etc.). `this` is apparently not what you expect. You haven't shown us the context of that code, so we can't help you with it, but it's going to come down to [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) for some function where you're using `this.handleInputChange`. Look for `function` functions and method calls, those are where you're likely having trouble.